# The indefinite article - which sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar

> There is a big and comfortable bed in my room.

or

> There is a big and a comfortable bed in my room.

Comment: The role of the determiner "a" is to mark a noun phrase as indefinite. Since "big and comfortable bed" is just a single noun phrase, you only need to mark it once, so your first example is the correct one.

Comment: How many beds are in your room? The second sentence is correct if there are two beds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former is correct, as big and comfortable are adjectives of bed.

> There is a big, long, green and comfortable bed.

In the second sentence, the word *a* denotes a new item in your list.

> There is a bed, a chair, a sofa, and a window in the room.

Combining these ideas you'd get something like:

> There is a brown bed, a purple chair, and a big and comfortable bed in the room.

Often the 'and' is omitted though when chaining adjectives:

> There is a brown bed, a purple chair, and a big comfortable bed in the room.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question about your last example: There is a brown bed, a purple chair, and a big comfortable bed in the room. Why isn't there a comma after the word "big"?

Comment: A comma is optional, it sounds more natural with a comma so you are correct. It is just about phrasing.